How to merge private arrays into a shared one in OMP - C?
I am trying to parallelize a program for finding local maxima using reduction. However, I am encountering a problem during the merging process: the merged array ends up containing exactly two fewer elements than it should.
Here's my code
    double start, stop;

    const float tab[40] = {smth...};
    float maxV3[N];
    int nb_max_locaux = 0;

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        float maxTemp[N];
        int k = 0;
        int j = 0;

#pragma omp for reduction(+:nb_max_locaux)
        for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
            if ((tab[i - 1] < tab[i]) && (tab[i + 1] < tab[i])) {
                maxTemp[nb_max_locaux] = tab[i];
                nb_max_locaux++;
                k++;
            }
        }

#pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < nb_max_locaux; i++) {
            if (j < k) {
                maxV3[i] = maxTemp[j++];
            }
        }
    }


I have tried debugging the issue and discovered that some threads, which hold several elements, complete their iterations without fully emptying their local arrays.
P.S. When running the same code with a small number of threads (e.g., 3), the final result is correct.

I think maxTemp[nb_max_locaux] is forbidden in a reduction(+:nb_max_locaux) loop because this is not just a reduction anymore, but a scan (i.e. cumsum) : each threads needs not only to compute the final sum but also read the sum so far (while using multiple threads). As a result the current loop contains a race condition.

If your condition is rarely taken, you can just use an atomic increment (and also tell the compiler that your loop is rarely taken so it can possibly vectorize it resulting in a much faster code). Otherwise, you need a parallel scan, but this is not easy to do efficiently unfortunately and here this probably not worth it at all because there is just not enough computation (the operation might be memory bound).

By the way, note that it does not worth using multiple threads to do this computation on 40 items (you use N but tab has a limited size of 40 so N is limited too because of tab[i] with i in [1;N-1[)...

You need nb_max_locaux to be atomic, i think openmp provides that, also i think the C standard library provides atomic operations, you need an atomic increment.

I suspect you meant to write maxTemp[k] = tab[i]; -- that way, each thread fills a contiguous region of its private maxTemp, which seems to be what the trailing loop expects.  But that still leaves you with a problem if the first loop is scheduled differently than the second (and this may be the problem).  You need each thread to have the same number of iterations of the second loop scheduled to it as it had iterations of the first loop, else it won't copy out the right number of elements.  Perhaps you can ensure this with a static schedule.

@JohnBollinger inside the loop k is equal to nb_max_locaux. The neutral element for addition is 0, which is used to initialize a "+" reduction. K and nb_max_locaux are both initially 0. K I used to count the thread-local elements, nb_max_locaux calculates the total number of elements.

The reason for your observed behavior is the work distribution in your final for loop. Although you do not specify a schedule, most implementations will use a static schedule distributing the iterations equally to the threads. If not all threads detected the same number of local maxima, some thread will have to few iterations to write out all its values.
Using an atomic index, the code can look like:
    const float tab[40] = {smth...};
    float maxV3[N];
    int nb_max_locaux = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
        if ((tab[i - 1] < tab[i]) && (tab[i + 1] < tab[i])) {
#pragma omp atomic capture
            int index = nb_max_locaux++;
            maxTemp[index] = tab[i];
        }
    }

This will lead to contention for atomically incrementing nb_max_locaux and also writing to maxTemp[]. The latter is caused by random threads writing to the same cache line.
This solution will also not preserve the ordering of the values.
